# Active Directory in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, active-directory

How can I get a list of computers and their properties from Active Directory using VB.Net and Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 3):

You're going to want to use the **System.DirectoryServices** or the **System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement** to access your domain.

These namespaces have classes you can use to search your directory and examine the objects it finds.

Is there something you're looking for in particular?

(it's worth noting that is most cases you need to add a reference to these namespaces in your project)

Answer (score 2):

Working with Active Directory, even with the help of the DirectorySearcher class, is no mean feat. It is not a task to be taken lightly. If you haven't done it before, I'd read up on it before attempting to do so.

I highly recommend [The .NET Developer's Guide to Directory Services Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321350170).

That being said, the classes in the DirectoryServices namespace do some of the work for you, but certainly nowhere near enough of it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [DirectorySearcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.aspx) class.